# What's the problem causing this ring-shaped artifact in my image even though I have cleaned my lens?

Tags: artifacts, cleaning

I can't see any physical problems on my lens, and sufficiently cleaned it, but see a ring shape in my footage such as...

[image]

I only have one lens so can't check if it's the camera or lens
Any tips or insight would be a huge help!

Comment: Did you clean only the front element? That looks like it could be something on the rear element, or even on the sensor itself... The front element can actually be surprisingly dirty without showing too much ill effect, and a spot on the front element will not generally be visible as a spot in the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on its shape and brightness profile (bright rim, dimmer center), and the fact it's in the same location on multiple frames, I believe this is a dust mote on the sensor.

If your camera has a removable lens, and you can lock the mirror up (assuming you have one) you can probably use an air bulb (I think of them as a negative blower, because I learned on film) to remove the dust -- recognizing, of course, the risk you'll just move it, or even allow more to settle there.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, there are sensor cleaning kits available from the larger photography stores online.  READ AND FOLLOW the INSTRUCTIONS and also check with your cameras manufacturer (or at least instructions) to avoid possible damage to the sensor.  The same rule applies as cleaning lenses: DON'T.  If you absolutely *must*, do it as gently and carefully as possible.  A damaged sensor is a trashed camera body...

Comment: Turns out there was a smudge on the sensor! I managed to carefully rub it off after getting a lens cleaning kit online.

Comment: @Jonathan Hopefully you didn't damage the sensor by ignoring my third paragraph...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Hopefully he found instructions that had actual directions on how to carefully clean a sensor...

Comment: Problem is a lens cleaning kit doesn't have tools that are safe for sensors, other than possibly a squeeze bulb.  Brush = bad.  Moist wipe = worse, and likely to make more new smudges than it removes.  Sensor cleaning kits I've seen have a very soft (but not foam) rubber wiper for the sensor surface; used like a squeegee, roughly.